# facebook connect: thumbnail images broken up in FB.Connect.streamPublish pop-up prompt, and on wall for a few minutes

Tags: php, image, proxy, facebook

I'm using facebook connect so that users can publish comments they are leaving on my site on their facebook wall as well.

It works as intended, except that in the confirmation pop up, the thumbnail image i provide is broken. Looking at the source, I can see that facebook prepended my image url like this:

from: http://www.mysite.com/path/to/my/image.jpg

to:

http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=303377111175&v=1&size=z&cksum=41a391c9f3a6f3dde2ede9892763c943&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fmy%2image.jpg

The image on the facebook user's wall has the same prepended url, and is also broken for a couple of minutes, after which it's showing up correctly. But obviously, having a broken image in the confirmation window and on your wall for a couple of minutes is not a good experience...

Has anybody experienced the same / knows how to work around this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Martin

PS: here's the part of the js call, if it's of any use...

```
attachment = {
'media': [{ 'type': 'image', 'src': 'http://www.mysite.com/path/to/my/image.jpg', 'href': 'http://www.mysite.com/the/current/page' }]
};
FB.Connect.streamPublish(user_message, attachment, action_links, target_id, user_message_prompt, fbcallback, false, actor_id)
```

Comment: I have the same problem can you please explain what is "dev" adn how I should change the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, i figured it out:

i was trying to post from dev.mysite.com, but referenced www.mysite.com in the image urls... changed image urls to dev. and now it's working like a charm...

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having *exactly* the same problem (dev.mysite.com instead of just mysite.com) and thanks to you I saved some time.